# Run Through a MongoDB collection in reverse mode

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have a collection "collection_Save" in mongoDB that contains documents
that are used to save the operations that occur on others documents in an other collection. They are listed by order of creation in the database. 
In order to reverse those operations I need to run through the collection from the end to the start.

This is where I can't figure out how to do. Since MongoCollection doesn't have the equivalent of a "Reverse" method.

I tried to create an index using the following code

```
 collection_Save.CreateIndex(IndexKeys<SaveMongo>.Ascending(_ => _._id));
```

but I can't figure out how to use it (or if it is really helpful in my case).

I did find something that might be useful : [MongoRestore, skip n first documents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24775881/mongorestore-skip-n-first-documents/24777523#24777523)

However they are not working in c# and my low reputation prevents me from commenting the post.

Do you know how to run through a collection in "reverse mode" ?

Comment: What is the field you want to be sorted by?

Comment: I don't really want to sort my documents. I just want to have acess to all the fields in the last document created, then the last-1 document, then the last-2 document, and so on and on on until I have access to the fields in the first document.

Comment: do you want to access **one** document per query?

Comment: yes. I need to access the document one by one (every time I access a document, I do some operations according to what the fields in the document contain. Then I am ready for the previous document)

Comment: I am afraid you cannot force MongoDB to store your documents in a particular order. What you can do is request the documents to appear in a particular order. Let me post an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create an index on your `date` field like this:

```
db.collection_Save.createIndex({date: -1})
```

then you can query your collection in this way:

```
db.collection_Save.find().sort({date: -1}).skip(last_n).limit(1)
```

where `last_n` is the number (counted from the end) of the document you want to get.

Comment: What is the "timestamp" field, I don't have any in my document (I have a "DateTime date" for the date of creation is all)

Comment: I mean the field that contains the creation time. Updated the answer.

Comment: Visual studio is pointing out an error with the syntax "createIndex({date: -1}) : "Invalid expression term '{'" when I pass over the "({date" part  and "only an assignation, an increment, a decrement, an expectation, and an object expression can be used as instructions" when I pass over the "-1" part

Comment: My code is javascript mongo shell, cant yoy transform it to c#?

Comment: I am currently trying yes. I'll keep you informed of the whereabouts

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78173/discussion-between-n9code-and-nicolasr).

Comment: It doesn't matter how you create the index. All that matters is the sort.